# Basic tooltip will not animate when mouse is hovered off link

Tags: jquery

my code is very simple, i am avoiding the use of a plugin, here it is:

```
**CSS**

.tooltip{
display:none;
height:100px;
width:100px;
background-color:#000;
}

**HTML**

<a href="#" class="testing">
link 
<div class="tooltip">
<!--information goes here -->
</div>
</a>


**JQUERY**
$('.testing').live('hover',function(){
$(this).children('.tooltip').fadeIn(300);},
function(){$(this).children('.tooltip').fadeOut(300);});
```

the problem is, when the mouse leaves the link, the div "tooltip" does not fadeout, my assumption is because i am using .live() , can anyone help me with a workaround?

Comment: just so you know, i have to use live()

Comment: can confirm, .live() is where the problem lies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$('.testing').live("mouseenter",function(){$(this).children('.tooltip').fadeIn(300);})
  .live("mouseleave", function() {
  $(this).children('.tooltip').fadeOut(300);
});
```

Working demo at http://jsbin.com/ewivo/2

Comment: seems to be working for me! thanks a ton for the help, wouldn't know what to do without the fine people here. thanks again!

Comment: @mcbeav : its a give and take thing.You give us problems , we give you solutions and also get something to learn. :)